# How to find cumulative some by row (not column) in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

How can SQL (Redshift) create a cumulative sum by row, not column. For example,

Input table:

```
id, week_1, week_2, week_3, week_4
__________________________________
'A',    10,     20,     30,     40
'B',    20,     40,     60,     80
```

Desired Output:

```
id, week_1, week_2, week_3, week_4
__________________________________
'A',    10,     30,     60,     100
'B',    20,     60,    120,     200
```

The method will group by id then compute cumulative sum by row of the columns week_1...week_4 in this order.

Answer (score -1):

You can keep it simple and aggregate each column like so:

```sql
        select id,
               week1,
               (week1 + week2) as week2,
               (week1 + week2 + week3) as week3,
               (week1 + week2 + week3 + week4) as week4
          from t;
```

Here is a [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6kjRsy5fr5t3fx8Cn9QR2N/0) example if you want to experiment with the solution.

Comment: And what about an edge case where I need the previous 50, 100 or 1000 weeks?